# Salesforce Internal Error in Lightning with Gack Id -1475846362

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, gack

While using  tag Salesforce Internal Error in Lightning with Gack Id -1475846362 is shown.

Why this might happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you miss value parameter on ui:outputURL tag this error may occur.

=========

Update: as sfdcfox suggests, this may also happen while missing a required attribute on a custom written component.

Comment: I also managed to get this gack while missing a required attribute on a custom component I'd written. I'm trying to get a repro right now.

Comment: Thanks. It is strange that the same gack id appears in unrelated cases and related cases may have different gack id